# How to use for loop inside Arrays.asList()

Tags: android, arrays, loops, for-loop, sharedpreferences

I have stuck to this code.
I want to build a listview with custom adapter.
I will read the data from SharedPreferences

The code working:

```
List<Data> list = Arrays.asList(

            new Data(910000, "Name", "Address", 59855, "City", "Tel", "Coms", -8860075),
            new Data(958568, "Name 2", "My home", 985, "Somewhere","Tel", "", -8860075),
            new Data(058460, "Name 3", "my work", 2584, "There", "Tel", "", -8860075)
    );
```

Now, I have predefined 3 orders.
But the user will add more orders, I will not know the total number (to be accurate, I will save the total number with data at sharedpreferences, and I will read them later)

How could I add a for loop inside Arrays.asList?

Comment: Y not just create the list and then add to the list one by one from a for loop? Why only use asList and why not just add?

Comment: Maybe I am lost on how to do that. I have tryied several ways, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Data data1 = new Data(910000, "Name", "Address", 59855, "City", "Tel", "Coms", -8860075);
    Data data2 = new Data(958568, "Name 2", "My home", 985, "Somewhere","Tel", "", -8860075);
    list.add(data1);
    list.add(data2);
```

Whenever you get new data create new Data object and add to the list

Comment: Hello, this working very well! Thank you very much!
But to understand what you do, to know how to work better in future, why you use ArrayList? Is it the same with Arrays.asList?

Comment: Arrays.asList converts array into list. Now question arises what is difference between array and arraylist ( http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2015/03/difference-between-array-and-arraylist-in-java-example.html). To create an array of object you need to give the size of the array. Suppose you given size as 10 and you want to add 11th element how you will do that. here Deep copy and Shallow copy comes into picture. Arraylist is a wrapper around array that does this job with more utility function. Please go deep through the Java collections also check Arraylist source code for deep understading

Answer (score 0):

Create a list first :

```
List<Data> list = new Arraylist<Data>();
```

When ever your user adds somethig to your list add it to the array:

```
list.add(new Data(910000, "Name", "Address", 59855, "City", "Tel", "Coms", -8860075))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of the question.

1) You have predefined data in your shared preferences.

2) You want to convert the data into a list of Objects (say contacts Data).

My suggestion would be, make use of getAll method of SharedPreferences.

```
Map<String, Data> contacts = sharedPreferences.getAll();

List<Data> contactsList = new ArrayList<>();

for(String contact: contacts.keySet()) {
    contactsList.add(contacts.get(contact));
}

//Process your list now in whatever way you want.
```

Hope this helps.